# How do I make sure unsupported (higher level) API is not called in Android?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, lint

I'm building an application for Gingerbread and up with `minSdkVersion=10` and `targetSdkVersion=17` in my AndroidManifest.xml.

I know that I should check if the API is supported before I call it, for example:

```
private void removeRule(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params, int rule) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) { // API 17
        params.removeRule(rule);
    } else {
        params.addRule(rule, 0);
    }
}
```

But sometimes I forget/or don't know I'm calling a higher level API and occasionally crash my program with `NoSuchMethodError` exception.

So before I publish my app, I always set my project to use Android SDK 2.3.3 and make sure I'm not making illegal method calls (e.g. all the errors I get are wrapped in an `if` statement checking the android SDK version), then set the SDK back to 4.2.2.

Is there a better way to make sure unsupported API is not called without switching the SDK?

(P.S. I'm using IntelliJ)

Comment: The right answer is "Use Lint" (http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html) as it will tell you when you use something newer than your `android:minSdkVersion`, but I'm not sure if there's IntelliJ integration for that yet. If not, you would need to run it from the command line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could (should) run Android Lint to check that:

Right click on the project (or package, class) > Analyze > Inspect Code.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about Android Lint. But I just tried it out, it seems it didn't catch the wrong API calls (using the above example, but remove the if statement check). :(

Comment: remove the `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` from your code, see where the Lint errors are, then put the suppression back and add the if statements where needed.

Comment: Possible reasons Lint is not catching the "NewAPI" error - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56427

Comment: in eclipse, it is now a button: "a checkbox with tick inside"

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse Properties --> Android Lint Preferences --> NewApi and change the Severity to Error.